# VB.net Convert Office Word Doc into Image?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to convert Word document to an Image so i can use iTextSharp to then convert the image to PDF. Please let me know if there is a free way to convert word file into an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the "Save As PDF" add-on for Word 2007 and higher to save the Word document directly as PDF.

If that doesn't meet your needs, you can search for some of the tools that let you "print to a file".  You could then print from Word to an image file and use iTextSharp to put that image into a PDF.

I'm not sure how many free solutions you'll find, but in the past, I developed a service that saved a Word doc as a PDF, then manipulated it with iTextSharp.  The only external expense for that was Word itself.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=F1FC413C-6D89-4F15-991B-63B07BA5F2E5&displaylang=en

Comment: Will you have Word running on the machine this will be running on? If so, just use the Word Save-As as @John Fisher pointed out.

Comment: I would like to do it all in memory and not save the file to disk.

Comment: @Mcdevitt:  You're dealing with Word files here.  If you want to avoid saving a file to disk, you'll need to pay for a third-party library that lets you convert Word documents, using streams.

Comment: What about iTextSharp will it let me covert Word documents to PDF's?

Comment: @Mcdevitt: Yes and No.  iTextSharp lets you create PDFs, but it doesn't know anything about Word.  So it will "let" you, but probably not the way you were asking.

Comment: John I am not sure what you mean can you please explain, Can i convert the word document into System.Drawing.Image and from there use iTextSharp to convert into the PDF file?

Comment: @Mcdevitt: You will need a third-party software package to turn a Word document into an image.

Comment: Do you know any that are free and I can do it in a memory stream?